# Group collections on the basis of Id using linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a three different collections named as Collection1,Collection2,Collection3. Now I want to group them up by their Id's also want to order that Id's on the basis of max count of them . The third thing that I want is to add that value to a Icollection . 
I have collections as follows:

```
Collection1:
   value1
   Id1
   value2 
   ...

Collection2:
   value1
   Id1
   value2 
   Id2
   ...

Collection3:
   value1
   Id1
   value2 
   Id2
   ...
```

Note: The Id's are unique in a collection. Id1 of collection1 or collection2 or collection3 can be same but inside a collection Id cannot be same.
What I have done is as follows:

```
var query = Collection1.Concat.Select(a => a.CountryId).Concat(Collection2.Select(b => b.CountryId).Concat(Collection3.Select(c => c.CountryId).GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```

For assigning that value to ICollection variable this is what i have done:

```
 foreach (var item in query )
 {
   ICollect.Add(item.Key);
 }
```

I am not sure about using `.ToDictionary`. Can anyone suggest a different approach for this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to merge all collections and group by the ID? Since the IDs are unique in every collection the group-size can have a maximum of 3.

```
var allIDs = Collection1.Select(x => x.ID)
    .Concat(Collection2.Select(x => x.ID))
    .Concat(Collection3.Select(x => x.ID))
    .GroupBy(id => id)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
    .Select(g => g.Key);

foreach(var id in allIDs)
    otherCollection.Add(id);
```

If you want to keep the count of each ID you could use `ToLookup`:

```
var idLookup = Collection1.Select(x => x.ID)
    .Concat(Collection2.Select(x => x.ID))
    .Concat(Collection3.Select(x => x.ID))
    .ToLookup(id => id)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count());
foreach(var g in idLookup)
{
    otherCollection.Add(g.Key);
    // you get the count in this way:
    int count = g.Count();
}
```